# How to add a key/value pairs to all AppResources.resx files?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, localization, windows-phone

my app supports both English and French. When I had just a Resource file for default language, English, I added some key/value pairs to the `AppResources.resx` file. then I added french language and a `AppResources.fr.resx` file appeared. So I just changed values of keys to french alternative.

Now I have added some new key/values to english, but I want it to automatically generate these keys in french file too so I change values again.

Is there a way to add new added keys to other resource files automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I use App Multilingual Toolkit. It's from Microsoft and it's amazingly easy to use.

You can find it on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj569303.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use [RESX Synchronizer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15697/RESX-Synchronizer) on my projects and it works perfectly well for synchronizing Resx files.

Here is the command that syncs your Neutral language Resx with the other ones:

```
resxsync ..\Resources.resx *
```

Answer (score 0):

The multilingual app toolkit that you can download [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/hh848309.aspx) and can find a tutorial [here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Adding_multilingual_support_to_your_Windows_Phone_application_using_the_Multilingual_App_Toolkit) can help you with synchronizing the different ResX. It has also some other features such as using bing to help you translate some of the string.